# How to read a ".wav" file into MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, wav

I wanted to input a wave file in the MATLAB so that I could process it using filters, when I come to input the wave file called `wave.wav`, this file is located on my desktop, and then I used

```
[y, fs, nb] = wavread('wave.wav');
```

to read the wave file but always gives me an error `cannot open file`, the only thing I can think of is that the function doesnt know the path of the `wave.wav`, any help?
And how can I play the file also using MATLAB after read, `sound()`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct on both counts.  Use the full path to the file, and use the `sound` function to play it back.  See [this reference page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/wavread.html) for a thorough example.  The documentation from the Mathworks is quite comprehensive.

Comment: Yes it worked but when i play the sound , the tone coming out is not the same as the actual tone, i think it just include the background tone or something how can i resolve this ??

Comment: @Shadi Plot it to see what it going on.  If you have an oscilloscope trace of the pure sound, compare your Matlab import against that.  Where does the original tone come from?  Are there filters on the original tone?  If so, you'll have to apply those to your waveform in Matlab.
Also, that page I quoted before says that you can use the import wizard to bring in a file.  Try it through that means also.

Answer (score 1):

This works:
[y,Fs]=wavread('filename');
sound(y,Fs);

note: the filename could be any audio file. but use a converter from .mp3 to .wav coz filename must be in wav format( few even say that waveread converts the file automatically into .wav file but in my case it did not!! )
:)

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path to the file and you can play the sound using `soundsc(y,fs)` instead `sound`

Comment: how do i know the fs of the input wave so that the sound output would be correct

Comment: @Shadi The information on sampling rate is on the page that I linked, too.  Please read that carefully.