# Read wav segment in matlab

Tags: matlab, wav

How to read a particular phoneme generated using htk mlf file in Matlab. I want to access the particular time duration of phoneme in MLF file. For example if the phoneme segment is `200000 800000 dh` I want to read the wave file at 0.2 ms to 0.8 ms

Answer (score 1):

You can [read the file as a whole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319870/how-to-read-a-wav-file-into-matlab), and cut segments you need

```
[signal, fs] = wavread('file.wav')

start_sample = fs * 200000 / 1000000
end_sample = fs * 800000  / 1000000

phoneme_signal = signal(start_sample:end_sample)
```

You can also specify the range in wavread if you know the frequency already:

```
start_sample = fs * 200000 / 1000000
end_sample = fs * 800000  / 1000000

[phoneme_signal, fs] = wavread('file.wav', [start_sample, end_sample])
```

Comment: Note that he said 0.2 ms, not 0.2 second

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `audioread` function which provides a `samples` argument letting you specify the beginning and the end of the signal you want to acquire :

```
% Suppose 'Fs' is the sampling frequency %
begin = 2^(-5) * Fs;
end = 8^(-5) * Fs;
[signal, fs] = audioread('file.wav', [begin,end]);
```